# Why do multiple short Tasks end up getting the same id?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a list of items to process, and I create a task for each one, and then await using Task.WhenAny(). I am following the pattern described here: [Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) .

I have changed one thing: I am using `HashSet<Task>` instead of `List<Task>`. But I notice that all the tasks end-up getting the same id, and thus the `HashSet` only adds one of them, and hence I end up waiting for only one task.

I have a working example here in dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQN2ow

Also pasting the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReproTasksWithSameId
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> itemIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            await ProcessManyItems(itemIds);
        }

        private static async Task ProcessManyItems(List<int> itemIds)
        {
            //
            // Create tasks for each item and then wait for them using Task.WhenAny
            // Following Task.WhenAny() pattern described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete
            // But replaced List<Task> with HashSet<Task>.
            //

            HashSet<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

            // We map the task ids to item ids so that we have enough info to log if a task throws an exception.
            Dictionary<int, int> taskIdToItemId = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (int itemId in itemIds)
            {
                Task task = ProcessOneItem(itemId);
                Console.WriteLine("Created task with id: {0}", task.Id);
                tasks.Add(task);
                taskIdToItemId[task.Id] = itemId;
            }

            // Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain.
            while (tasks.Count > 0)
            {
                // Identify the first task that completes.
                Task task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

                // Remove the selected task from the list so that we don't
                // process it more than once.
                tasks.Remove(task);

                // Get the item id from our map, so that we can log rich information.
                int itemId = taskIdToItemId[task.Id];

                try
                {
                    // Await the completed task.
                    await task;  // unwrap exceptions.
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully processed task with id: {0}, itemId: {1}", task.Id, itemId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to process task with id: {0}, itemId: {1}. Just logging & eating the exception {1}", task.Id, itemId, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        private static async Task ProcessOneItem(int itemId)
        {
            // Assume this method awaits on some asynchronous IO.
            Console.WriteLine("item: {0}", itemId);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is this:

```
item: 1
Created task with id: 1
item: 2
Created task with id: 1
item: 3
Created task with id: 1
item: 4
Created task with id: 1
Successfully processed task with id: 1, itemId: 4
```

So basically the program exits after awaiting just the first task.

1. **Why do multiple short Tasks end up getting the same id?** BTW I also tested with a method that returns `Task<TResult>` instead of `Task`, and in that case it works fine.
2. **Is there a better approach I can use?**

Comment: That's not a pattern, it's just a doc example that demonstrates tasks. It's *not* meant for production scenarios, except for very simple cases. There are far better classes that deal with pub/sub, multiple workers and tasks like Dataflow's ActionBlock<> and System.Threading Channels.

Comment: As for your specific question - where's the async code? There are no live tasks in this code. The compiler should have emitted a warning already that `ProcessOneItem` doesn't contain `await` and thus will run synchronously. There are no tasks here, everything runs on the main thread

Comment: You're running the code synchronously, it returns the same *completed* task each time. Add a `await Task.Delay(100);` in that method and it will return new tasks.

Comment: `Is there a better approach I can use?` To do *what*? The specifics matter. Processing 1000 URLs requires a different *architecture* from processing 100K in-memory elements

Comment: `await Task.Delay(100);` to at least implement the `IAsyncStateMachine` sufficiently

Comment: Anyway all this code is to prove tasks have different ID's what is it you really want to do

Comment: In my real code `ProcessOneItem` does do some async work (unlike the repro above). I am actually seeing this issue in unit tests. I mocking the async work that it does in test, and that is where I am actually seeing this issue. Thanks for the pointer on `ActionBlock`. I will take a look.

Comment: Does the mock actually _execute_ async?

Comment: I am working on creating a sample unit test so that I can show exactly how I am mocking. I will update here shortly.

Comment: By implication, if they all get the same ID, then they were never running *concurrently*. By further implication then, waiting on just one of them is sufficient to know that they've all finished working.

Comment: You guys are right. I think I need to reframe my question into "how to appropriately unit test such a code that is shown above?". Working on a sample.

Comment: Since you have an answer to this, probably best to mark it as such, and ask a new question

Comment: @Turbo what do you want to do? The *better* option would be to use eg Dataflow or Channels. This code is only suitable for a doc example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question's code is synchronous so there's only one completed task going around. `async` doesn't make something run asynchronously, it's syntactic sugar that allows using `await` to await an *already* executing asynchronous operation to complete without blocking the calling thread.

As for the documentation example, that's what it is. A documentation example, not a pattern and *certainly* not something that can be used in production except for simple cases.

What happens if you can only make 5 requests at a time to avoid flooding your network or CPU? You'd need to download only a fixed number of records for that.  What if you need to *process* the downloaded data? What if the list of URLs comes from *another* thread?

Those issues are handled by concurrent containers, pub/sub patterns and the purpose-built Dataflow and Channel classes.

**Dataflow**

The older Dataflow classes take care of buffering input and output and handling worker tasks automatically. The entire download code can be replaced with an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.0):

```
var client=new HttpClient(....);
//Cancel if the process takes longer than 30 minutes
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10,
    BoundedCapacity=5,
    CancellationToken=cts.Token
};
var block=new ActionBlock<string>(url=>ProcessUrl(url,client,cts.Token));
```

That's it. The block will use up to 10 concurrent tasks to perform up to 10 concurrent downloads. It will keep up to 5 urls in memory (it would buffer everything otherwise). If the input buffer becomes full, sending items to the block will await asynchronously, t thus preventing slow downloads from flooding memory with URLs.

On the same or a different thread, the "publisher" of urls can post as many URLs as it wants, for as long as it wants.

```
foreach(var url in urls)
{
    await block.SendAsync(url);
}
//Tell the block we're done
block.Complete();
//Wait until all downloads are complete
await block.Completion;
```

We can use other blocks like TransformBlock to produce output, pass it to another block and thus, create a concurrent processing pipeline. Let's say we have two methods, `DownloadURL` and `ParseResponse` instead of just `ProcessUrl` :

```
Task<string> DownloadUrlAsync(string url,HttpClient client)
{
    return client.GetStringAsync(url);
}

void ParseResponse(string content)
{
    var object=JObject.Parse();
    DoSomethingWith(object);
}
```

We could create a separate block for each step in the pipeline, with different DOP and buffers :

```
var dlOptions=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5,
    BoundedCapacity=5,
    CancellationToken=cts.Token
};
var downloader=new TransformBlock<string,string>(
                   url=>DownloadUrlAsync(url,client),
                   dlOptions);

var parseOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10,
    BoundedCapacity=2,
    CancellationToken=cts.Token
};
var parser=new ActionBlock<string>(ParseResponse);

downloader.LinkTo(parser, new DataflowLinkOptions{PropageateCompletion=true});
```

We can post URLs to the downloader now and wait until all of them are parsed. By using different DOP and capacities, we can balance the number of downloader and parser tasks to download as many URLs as we can parse and handle eg slow downloads or big responses.

```
foreach(var url in urls)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(url);
}
//Tell the block we're done
downloader.Complete();
//Wait until all urls are parsed
await parser.Completion;
```

**Channels**

[System.Threading.Channels](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) introduces Go-style channels. These are actually lower-level concepts that a Dataflow block. If Channels were available back in 2012, they'd be written using channels.

An equivalent download method would look like this :

```
ChannelReader<string> Downloader(ChannelReader<string> ulrs,HttpClient client,
                                 int capacity,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateBounded(capacity);
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var url in urls.ReadAsStreamAsync(token))
        {
            var response=await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            await writer.WriteAsync(response);
        }
    }).ContinueWith(t=>writer.Complete(t.Exception));
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

That's more verbose but it allows us to do things like create the HttpClient *in* the method and reuse it. Using a ChannelReader as both input and output may look weird, but now we can chain such methods simply by passing an output reader as input to another method.

The "magic" is that we create a worker task that waits to process messages and return a reader immediatelly. Whenever a result is produced, it's sent to the channel and the next step in the pipeline.

To use multiple worker tasks, we can use `Enumerable.Range` to start many of them and use `Task.WhenAny` to close the channel when all channels are done :

```
ChannelReader<string> Downloader(ChannelReader<string> ulrs,HttpClient client,
                                 int capacity,int dop,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateBounded(capacity);
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    var tasks  = Enumerable
                   .Range(0,dop)
                   .Select(_=> Task.Run(async ()=>{
                       await foreach(var url in urls.ReadAllAsync(token))
                       {
                           var response=await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                           await writer.WriteAsync(response);
                       }
                    });
    _=Task.WhenAll(tasks)
          .ContinueWith(t=>writer.Complete(t.Exception));
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

Publishers can create their own channel and pass a reader to the `Downloader` method. They don't need to publish anything in advance either :

```
var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
var dlReader=Downloader(channel.Reader,client,5,5);
foreach(var url in someUrlList)
{
    await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(url);
}
channel.Writer.Complete();
```

**Fluent pipelines**

This is so common that someone could create an extension method for this. Eg, to convert an IList to a `Channel<T>`, we don't need to wait as all the results are already available :

```
ChannelReader<T> Generate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<T>();
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        channel.Writer.TryWrite(T);
    }
    channel.Writer.Complete();
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

If we convert the `Downloader` to an extension method too, we can use :

```
var pipeline= someUrls.Generate() 
                      .Downloader(client,5,5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Reading about this.

Comment: @Turbo added another section about Channels

Comment: Dataflow is is the correct tool for this job IMHO. It is a complete solution that covers both buffering and processing. Channels are great for buffering (actually may be the perfect async queues), but offer no help at the processing part. So you end up spawning tasks manually and writing suboptimal processing loops with problematic exception handling characteristics. For example with the second `Downloader` in the example, a single exception will kill a worker task, reducing the degree of parallelism. The error will not be propagated until all urls are processed, or all workers are dead.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `ProcessOneItem` is not async.

You should see the following warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Once you add `await (...)` to `ProcessOneItem` the return task will have a [unique-ish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) id.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`Task.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id) property:

> Task IDs are assigned on-demand and do not necessarily represent the order in which task instances are created. Note that although collisions are very rare, task identifiers are not guaranteed to be unique.

From what I understand this property is mainly there for debugging purposes. You should probably avoid depending on it for production code.