# Deadlock while debugging using HttpClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, deadlock, dotnet-httpclient

I have to query a external webservice using HttpClient (sending hundreds of requests).
I made a classic async await loop using HttpClient but, while debugging, about 5-10% of the time Visual Studio freezes, not sure if it's a deadlock or not. Cancellation tokens are not working, I have to kill process using task manager.
Still I've got 0 issue when starting program using command prompt.

Code freezes on `SendAsync`. Sometimes after just 3 to 4 HTTP requests.
The targeted service is a notable hotel's supplier (could not share ids), I will use a `SemaphoreSlim` throttler in the final version.

Using .NET 5.0.18 (.NET 4.5)
Visual Studio 2019 (16.11)

I read [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42375) and disabled `System.Runtime.TieredCompilation` and `System.Runtime.ProfApi_RejitOnAttach` in my `runtimeconfig.template.json` but this did not fix my problem.

```
public class WebServiceCaller {
    //wont be release atm
    protected static readonly HttpClient clientSingleton = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<string> CallerAynx(List<string> urls) {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(30000);
        Stopwatch watchTime = new Stopwatch();
        watchTime.Start();
        string formattedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        //KO while debuging about 10% of the time after 2=> 6 http SendAsync call
        urls.ForEach(url => {
            taskList.Add(HttpClientToolsSendAsync(url, cts.Token));
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList).ConfigureAwait(false);


        //work when using a thread pool
        await Task.Run(() =>  urls.ForEach(url =>  {
            taskList.Add(HttpClientToolsSendAsync(url, cts.Token));
        }));
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList).ConfigureAwait(false);


        watchTime.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Final ASYNC: {watchTime.Elapsed}");
        return "OK";
    }

    private async Task<string> HttpClientToolsSendAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  {
        //wathever for the moment
        string result = string.Empty;
        try  {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };
            //my ids
            string clearIds = "Login:Password";
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Base64Encode(clearIds));

            //deadlock - bug here
            var response = await clientSingleton.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);;
            }
            else {
                result = "KOHTTP";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  {
            //fire or forget, we dont really want to manage exception
            //wont be catch by tasks.when all
            result = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static string Base64Encode(string textToEncode) {
        byte[] textAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncode);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(textAsBytes);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //i have a function generating my url here
            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            WebServiceCaller caller = new WebServiceCaller();
            //configure await added everywhere because this code could be used as a library later
            await caller.CallerAynx(urls).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

[image: visualstudiofreeze]

Comment: Do not share `HttpClient` between threads. Use `HttpClientFactory` instead and let every thread use its own `HttpClient`.

Comment: You need to dispose your `var response` with `using`. And you shouldn't be settting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` manually.

Comment: @Eldar `HttpClient` is thread safe as far as calling `SendAsync` is concerned.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`? Are you sure the bottleneck is not network or the server?

Comment: @PauloMorgado with task.Run this work 100% of the time while debuging (this is a step arround). The problem occurs in the loop without the Task.Run

Comment: Beware that .NET 5.0 has been out of support for almost 18 months and, if there's an issue with it, it won't be fixed. Does it work with .NET 6.0, .NET 7.0 or .NET 8.0?

Comment: I will install a visual 2022 and keep you informed

Comment: The "working" version is adding to the list concurrently; there's definitely a race condition there, so it is likely not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @Eldar HttpClient is perfectly thread-safe. HttpClientFactory is used to recycle sockets, not because of threading issues

Comment: @LeBigCat tasks aren't threads. There's rarely any reason to keep a list of tasks like this. If you want to hit 100 URLs concurrently, use `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls,...)`. The method `HttpClientToolsSendAsync` itself can be reduced to 1-3 lines, depending on whether the credentials are the same for all calls and can be set on HttpClient directly. If so, `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` is enough. You can store results in a `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: _"Using .NET 5.0.18 (.NET 4.5)"_ - so what are you actually using? .NET 5 or .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: The question's code looks like snippets copied from lots of SO questions or answers so it's way more complicated than it needs to be. If you want to process 100 URLs concurrently you'll find lots of SO answers posted by everyone who's commented until now. The solutions are typically *short*, and include `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, DataFlow, Channels. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826013/microsoft-tpl-dataflow-library-maxdegreeofparallelism-and-io-bound-work/74826198#74826198) for examples downloads, parses and imports results into a database using Dataflow

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426707/why-do-multiple-short-tasks-end-up-getting-the-same-id/58427166#58427166) both Dataflow and Channels are used for the same scenario. Nowadays the `await foreach` loop inside `Task.Run` would be replaced by `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.

Comment: @GuruStron: i messed, up :), i just checked System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription  , just pass to NET 5.0.17

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, migrated to 7.0 using Parallel.ForEachAsync. Seems "ok" for the moment, i will loop on it 100 times later to check if problem is solve. Thanks

Comment: @StephenCleary `.ForEach()` is a synchronous loop (essentially a `foreach` statement) so adding to the list is not happening concurrently. Obviously could be simplified to `var tasks = urls.Select(url => HttpClientToolsSendAsync(url, cts.Token)).ToArray();`

Comment: How many urls do you have there? and visual studio freezes due to 100% CPU perhaps?

Comment: Well, in debug i tested with someting like 12 urls. CPU is pretty low.